# Importing data and getting a PHP DateTimeZone error

Tags: php, datetime

Currently I am getting an error:

> DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()

The error is coming from this section of code - any ideas?

```
protected function _resolveTimeZone($timeZone, $useDst)
{
    $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $offset = $time->getTimezone()->getOffset($time) / 60 / 60;
    $timeZone = $this->_importModel->resolveTimeZoneOffset($offset, $useDst);
    return $timeZone;
}
```

Comment: What is value of `$timezone`?

Answer (score 1):

Rename `$timezone` to `$timeZone`. And check what `$timeZone` is one of supported time zones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php